# PHP: Combination of having and where not working in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause, having

I have a table named Messages where one entry contains the same as the following:

```
longtitude = 4.867478333333334
latitude = 52.31819833333334
username = 'pb'
```

If I query on the table with the below:

```
$longitude=4.867478333333334
$latitude=52.31819833333334
$username='pb'
$search=''
$visibledistance=2
```

using the below mysql query:

```
$query=("SELECT 
  subject,username,message,timestamp,(
    6371 * acos (
        cos ( radians('$latitude') )
      * cos( radians( Messages.latitude ) )
      * cos( radians( Messages.longitude ) - radians('$longitude') )
      + sin ( radians('$latitude') )
      * sin( radians( Messages.latitude ) )
    )
  ) AS distance FROM Messages WHERE username ='pb'  AND ((subject LIKE        '%$search%') OR (message LIKE '%$search%'))  GROUP BY subject  

HAVING distance < '$visibledistance' 
ORDER BY timestamp");
$sth = mysql_query($query);
```

I get no results. If I remove HAVING distance < '$visibledistance' I get all entries matching the remaining criterias, so there´s nothing wrong with anything but the distance part of it. Could someone help me to understand how I can do this right?

Thanks!

Comment: *"If I query on the table with the below:"* - Did you close off each statement? this being a technical sidenote for future (newbie) visitors who may think that that is valid syntax in php.

Comment: On the sidenote, i hope that this will never go into the code that is executed from the internet. It is the very definition of the SQL injection.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php and http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/5828/pdo/2685/preventing-sql-injection-with-parameterized-queries#t=201703091904411986445 for more information

Comment: Thanks, closeoff in which way do you mean?
No, this is still at test stage - later I´ll amend all my php code so that they´re injection proof.

Comment: @CoreyHart start from the beginning with the right foot, listen to the advice a newbie can give you. Your code should be ok from the beginning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have numeric value you should avoid the single quotes around the vars

and you should use concat for like

(for having if you use '$visibledistance' you are eval  `HAVING distance < '4'` (you are eval you distance respect to a string)

Looking to your code
you are not using an aggregation function so you don't need  having  you could use where (but noy alias) for fliter and distcint instead of group by

```
  $query=("SELECT distinct
    subject,username,message,timestamp,(
      6371 * acos (
          cos ( radians($latitude) )
        * cos( radians( Messages.latitude ) )
        * cos( radians( Messages.longitude ) - radians($longitude) )
        + sin ( radians($latitude) )
        * sin( radians( Messages.latitude ) )
      )
    ) AS distance FROM Messages WHERE username ='pb'  AND ((subject LIKE concat('%', '$search', '%') 
            OR (message LIKE concat('%','$search','%'))    

  WHERE (
      6371 * acos (
          cos ( radians($latitude) )
        * cos( radians( Messages.latitude ) )
        * cos( radians( Messages.longitude ) - radians($longitude) )
        + sin ( radians($latitude) )
        * sin( radians( Messages.latitude ) )
      )
    ) < $visibledistance 
  ORDER BY timestamp");
```

Comment: Thanks, I removed all single quotes from numeric values, but the result is the same. My suspicion is that this is related to addressing the latitude and longitude fields with "Messages.", since I saw other people dealing with this same task, who were encouraged to use JOIN, but I´m not sure if I really need to do that.

Comment: join or where condition do the same result  .. so  this i not the problem .. instead  check for real data ..  ... try get the real query builded  by php an try to exec it  in a sql IDE ....(could be also that $search = '' is not good)

Comment: What I mean is that I got it saying "messages.latitude" - never worked with adressing a column before this way. The search works fine as it is.. if I remove the HAVING, GROUP BY and ".............. AS distance" parts, things work fine - this is how it used to be, but now I need part of the query to take into consideration the coordinates, which is what I´m struggling with.

Comment: I'm sorry but  .. I realized now that it seems that you are using group by and having no one aggregate function .. (like sum. min.) .. because you are using group by? .. i have update the answer  with code using where instead of having

Comment: Allright thanks, still no luck but at least I have a better overview without the HAVING part - not sure why that´s used in all examples I found about this!

Comment: Hmm, is it not doing some twice here, querying on the whole longi/lati-formula?

Comment: I don't understand  you last comment please explain better  (in a  simple way)  .. what do you mean

Comment: You have 
(
      6371 * acos (
          cos ( radians($latitude) )
        * cos( radians( Messages.latitude ) )
        * cos( radians( Messages.longitude ) - radians($longitude) )
        + sin ( radians($latitude) )
        * sin( radians( Messages.latitude ) )
      )

appearing twice. Is that intentional?

Comment: Yes ... .. the use of an alias  in a where condition is not allowed  in sql  ... and you have not aggreagtion function so you don't should use group by and having ..-- having filter the result  ... where filter the selected rows ..

Comment: Ok,so I rewrote it to something that I got working:your inspiration and help got me there! 
$query=("SELECT  subject,username,message,timestamp FROM Messages WHERE username ='pb'  AND ((subject LIKE '%$search%') OR (message LIKE '%$search%'))   AND (
      6371 * acos (
          cos ( radians($latitude) )
        * cos( radians( Messages.latitude ) )
        * cos( radians( Messages.longitude ) - radians($longitude) )
        + sin ( radians($latitude) )
        * sin( radians( Messages.latitude ) )
      )
    ) < $visibledistance ORDER BY timestamp");
$sth = mysql_query($query);

Comment: Nope, now it does the job as it should! Do you see any issues with this approach?

Comment: The second answer  i provide .. is the right one  .. and is in the right way  .. (i remove the first because don't take in right consideration the absence of aggregation function) so  .. the answer  provided  have not particular issue  .. is written in the right way ..

Comment: I will indeed, but just wondering if my ammended version of your answer, cutting out the double query on distance and the "distinct" part is somewhat slower, would cause some issues or..?

Comment: Ah I think I got it.. you posted both answers in the same box? That´s why it´s double then :D